# $E$ a closed subscheme of $X$, the underlying topological space of $E \times_k \overline{k}$ does not depend on scheme structure on $E$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is similar to a question I just asked.  Let $X$ be a scheme over a field $F$, and let $E$ be a closed subset of $X$.  There are many different closed subscheme structures on $E$.

Let $L$ be a field containing $F$.  *Does the underlying topological space of the fiber product $E_L = E \times_{\textrm{Spec } F} \textrm{Spec } L$ depend on the choice of closed subscheme structure on $E$?*

In the affine case, it does not.  Let $A$ be an $F$-algebra, and let $I$ be an ideal of $A$.  Then $\textrm{Spec } A/I$ and $\textrm{Spec } A/\sqrt{I}$ are closed subschemes of $X = \textrm{Spec } A$ with the same underlying space.  When we base change to $L$, we are looking at the spectra of

$$A/I \otimes_F L = A \otimes_F L / (I \otimes_F L) $$

and $$A/\sqrt{I} \otimes_F L = A \otimes_F L/(\sqrt{I} \otimes_F L) $$

where $I \otimes_F L$ is the same thing as the $L$-span of the image of $I$ in $A \otimes_F L$.  We are done, because $I \otimes_F L$ and $\sqrt{I} \otimes_F L$ have the same radical: if $x \in \sqrt{\sqrt{I} \otimes L}$, then $x^n = \sum\limits_i a_i \otimes \lambda_i$ for some $a_i \in \sqrt{I}, \lambda_i \in L,$ and some $n$. Now raising $x^n$ to an even larger power ensures that it lands in $I \otimes_F L$.

Should this remain true outside the affine case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily show the following using only the universal properties of the fibre product and the reduced subscheme structure:

> If $T$ is reduced scheme with a map $T \to E \times_F L$, then this
>   map factors through $E_{red} \times_F L$.

In particular the map $(E \times_F L)_{red} \to E \times_F L$ factors as
$$(E \times_F L)_{red} \to E_{red} \times_F L \to E \times_F L.$$

Let $S$ be the underlying topological space of $E \times_F L$ and $S'$ the underlying topological space of $E_{red} \times_F L$. Apply the forgetful functor from schemes to topological spaces to the map above to get a map

$$S \to S' \to S$$
which is the identity map. In particular $S \cong S'$, i.e. $S$ does not depend on the closed subscheme structure of $E$, since it can be computed by using the unique reduced closed subscheme structure.

Comment: One should note that proof does not need that $F$ and $L$ are spectra of fields. This works for arbitrary schemes.

Comment: Thanks.  As a note to myself: $S' \rightarrow S$ is injective as a closed immersion (stable under base change, since $E_{red} \rightarrow E$ is a closed immersion)  It follows that composition in the other direction $S \rightarrow S' \rightarrow S$ is also the identity.

Comment: I thought like this, which is somehow the same: As the underlying map of topological spaces of a closed immersion the map $S' \to S$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. Since the composition is the identity, the image is $S$.